# JSTL formatNumber tag is generating unknown characters for group separators in utf-8

Tags: jsp, utf-8, internationalization, jstl

I'm trying to output numbers with groupings and decimal places in a JSP page using the JSTL formatNumber tag, similar to the following:

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${form.amount}" pattern='###,##0.00' />
```

It works fine for lang=en, fr, and es if the encoding is set to ISO-8859-1 in the  tag and page directive, but if I set it to UTF-8, lang=fr no longer works correctly.  The decimal point becomes a comma, as expected, but the group separator becomes a �.

As a test of the formatting, I left the pattern out, so I just had

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${form.amount}" />
```

and the result was the same.

As a test of the encoding, I've put some French characters in the page that aren't supported by ISO-8859-1, such as Œ, œ, and the very rare Ÿ, and they come through fine when the encoding is set to UTF-8, but they come through garbled when the encoding is set to ISO-8859-1, as expected, so it would seem that the encoding is being correctly set to UTF-8.  The browser also indicates that the encoding is UTF-8.

This is a Spring application and it's using the locale interceptor to set the locale based on a 'lang' parameter in the request.

What else can I try?

EDIT:  I think I've figured it out, but I'm not sure why what I did works.  I'm using Tiles and I have a main JSP file defining the layout of the page with 4 tiles defining sub-pages for meta, header, main, and footer areas.  I originally had <%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> only in the layout JSP, thinking that the tile definitions would inherit that, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  I need to add that directive to every page, which is a pain if I ever want to change.  Is that how it should work?

Comment: Look at answer at    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126542/how-to-set-jstl-locale-from-java-code

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the issue isn't with the locale - it's pulling messages from the correct resource bundle in the same JSP.  I'm pretty sure it's an encoding issue, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: As to the JSTL problem, I can't explain it based on the information provided so far. Perhaps you did something different or made an incorrect observation. An SSCCE would be helpful. As to the test of the encoding with hardcoded characters in source code files, you need to reconfigure your editor to save source code files using UTF-8. This is however a different problem than the JSTL one. See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338763/the-sign-is-shown-as-a-diamond-with-a-question-mark-in-the-middle/12340059#12340059

Comment: Thanks - I did reconfigure my editors to use UTF-8, so that's not the issue.  I think I've figured it out though - see my edit above.